# Excelで1つのプルダウンセル選択肢に応じて、複数の別セルプルダウン選択肢を変更する

Tags: excel

下記の表にある「重要度・概要・説明」はプルダウンセルです。
重要度の選択値によって、下記<各列の選択肢>のように概要・説明の選択項目を動的に変更したいのですが、Excelで設定方法が分かりません。

<各列の選択肢>
・重要度：S,A,B
・概要
重要度でSが選択されている場合：概要1,概要2,概要3
重要度でAが選択されている場合：概要4,概要5,概要6
重要度でBが選択されている場合：概要7,概要8,概要9
・説明
重要度でSが選択されている場合：説明1,説明2,説明3
重要度でAが選択されている場合：説明4,説明5,説明6
重要度でBが選択されている場合：説明7,説明8,説明9

[image: Excel画像]

お分かりの方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

知恵袋にてご回答を頂きました。

[Yahoo知恵袋の回答](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10204039505)